# Combine count of faculty with different name

Tags: php, sql, count, sum

I have a faculty that have 3 name which are JABFNT, FPKF and JABPN. I want to count the student in each name then combine it to be just one total only. In the database, the JABFNT has 2 student, FPKF has 1 student and JABPN has 1 student. So the output should have total of 4 student. I didn't found the solution on how to combine it so this is the code that I have tried but the output that I got is 0.

```
      include("../connection_jpp.php");

      $pengundi_FPKF = 0;
      $pengundi_JABFNT = 0;
      $pengundi_JABPN = 0;

      $sql_pengundi    = "SELECT * FROM pengundi WHERE aktif = 'Y'";
      $result_pengundi = mysql_query($sql_pengundi) or die("".mysql_error());
  
      include("../connection_jpp.php");
  
      while ($row_pengundi = mysql_fetch_array($result_pengundi))
      {
        include("../connection_jpp.php");
        $no_matrik = $row_pengundi['no_matrik'];
  
        include ("../../includefail/connection.php");
        $sql_peng           = "SELECT * FROM pelajar WHERE no_matriks = '$no_matrik'
                               AND kod_fakulti = 'FPKF' AND aktif = 'Y'";
        $result_peng        = mysql_query($sql_peng) or die("".mysql_error());
        $count_check_status = mysql_num_rows($result_peng);
  
        if ($count_check_status > 0)
        {
          $pengundi_FPKF = $pengundi_FPKF + 1;
        }

        $sql_pengundi        = "SELECT * FROM pelajar WHERE no_matriks = '$no_matrik'
                             AND kod_fakulti = 'JABFNT' AND aktif = 'Y'";
        $result_pengundi     = mysql_query($sql_pengundi) or die("".mysql_error());
        $count_check_stat = mysql_num_rows($result_pengundi);

        if ($count_check_stat > 0)
        {
          $pengundi_JABFNT = $pengundi_JABFNT + 1;
        }

        $sql_pengundii     = "SELECT * FROM pelajar WHERE no_matriks = '$no_matrik'
                             AND kod_fakulti   = 'JABPN' AND aktif = 'Y'";
        $result_pengundii  = mysql_query($sql_pengundii) or die("".mysql_error());
        $count_check_statuss = mysql_num_rows($result_pengundii);

        if ($count_check_statuss > 0)
        {
        $pengundi_JABPN = $pengundi_JABPN + 1;
        }


      }
      $total_FPKF   = $pengundi_FPKF;
      $total_JABFNT = $pengundi_JABFNT;
      $total_JABPN  = $pengundi_JABPN;
      $total_fac   = $total_FPKF + $total_JABFNT + $total_JABPN;
```

Comment: Any errors on your queries?

Comment: Nope. I just got 0 as the output.

Comment: `0` could mean false or zero records found on query. Where did you get this "output"? Help me help you. Assume im not on your computer

Comment: The best way to solve this problem is to use SQL only solution. SQL will work faster and positively affect on the further software support.

Comment: I mean when I echo this variable $total_fac   = $total_FPKF + $total_JABFNT + $total_JABPN;  its return 0. That's the output.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score -1):

why not combine the SQL query in one go?
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pelajar WHERE kod_fakulti IN ('JABFNT','FPKF', 'JABPN')` or using sub-query

edit:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pelajar WHERE kod_fakulti IN ('JABFNT','FPKF', 'JABPN') AND no_matriks='$no_matriks' AND aktif='Y'`

all this does is make the SQL query in one go instead of multiple query like your original query

Comment: @zimorok, I have tried the query you gave but its return the total of student in table pengundi which is 15. The output that I need should be 4.

Comment: @zerhez: coming back to your SQL query, you still need to add the `no_matriks` and `aktif` like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pelajar WHERE kod_fakulti IN ('JABFNT','FPKF', 'JABPN') AND no_matriks='$no_matrik' AND  aktif ='Y'`

Comment: @GetSet: I dont even care about downvote and you should not care too either. Not all error will magically provide you with actual error / exception that is debuggable.